# simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content

Tags: php

My PHP version is - 8.1

I'm trying to convert an XML response into an array in PHP using this code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, SimpleXMLElement::class, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$response = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

The response seems get converted alright when I dump and die `$response`

However an exception is still thrown:

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content') as this code block is surrounded in a try catch
```

**This code works inside on another system im working on which is PHP 7.2 and uses the exact same XML response**

I've been trying to find out if any additional changes needed to be made since upgrading to 8.1?

I've tried doing quick fixes using regex to remove the special characters but had no luck

Comment: What's the exact issue? Error message is correct but wrong data hasn't been a problem until 8.1? Error message is incorrect and there is no UTF-16 declaration? Error message is incorrect and there is no UTF-8 content?

Comment: Error message is correct, the encoding returned in the response is utf-16. One thing maybe i should have noted is that in the older system a guzzle client was being used to make the request. We are now using Laravels Http client

Comment: ive replictaed the older systems fetching job by using the guzzle client directly and i am still getting the same error

Comment: Fetching the file and parsing it as XML are entirely different tasks. I'm not familiar with Guzzle so I don't know whether it has the feature to re-encode text responses automagically, but it doesn't sound too reasonable. If the file is indeed invalid (is it?), then you were silencing the errors, they fixed the bug in SimpleXML or a warning was promoted to exception--it doesn't really matter: XML is not HTML, it isn't meant to be invalid at all. There's no simple solution to corrupted XML.

Comment: ive validated my xml response and have got no issues with it (w3schools xml validator)

what i tried next was i used this regex to only include characters i needed
```$response = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9<>:=."\/\- ]/', " ", $response);```


i took that $reponse and made sure it was valid so i ran it through the same validator and all was good

however when i run it through simplexml_load_string() i now get this:
```simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name```

this is strange as the w3schools xml validator should pick up such errors

Comment: Do you need help determining the encoding of a file? To see the _declared_ encoding, you need to check the HTTP response for a `Content-Type` header (though it's probably irrelevant in this case) and you need to inspect the actual file contents to find an `encoding` attribute (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`). Seeing the _actual_ encoding is trickier. You can try an editor that displays the autodetected encoding (Visual Studio Code, for instance) and visually inspect looking for wrongly displayed characters (e.g. `�` or `Ã¡`). An [hex editor](https://hexed.it/) can also help.

Comment: You'll have a problem if you have _mixed_ encodings (i.e., part of the file uses UTF-16 and part uses UTF-8), but converting between encodings is trivial. And it's always possible that whoever generates the invalid XML is not aware of their issue and may be willing to fix it at source. (It's also possible that XML is just valid and it's the processing code the one that's wrong... That's why I'm suggesting to make a proper diagnostic.)